# Customize Media Controller

Tags: android, mediacontroller

I m using `VideoView` to display video.

My Requirement is a `MediaController` wid `play/Pause, Stop, & Volume Contoller`..
i tried

```
         MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);  
         View mMediaControllerView = (View)findViewById(R.id.mediaController1); 
         mc.setAnchorView(mMediaControllerView);
         videoView.setMediaController(mc);
```

adding an `imageview` to the `layout` but this seems to have no effect on the `MediaController`

need some guidance/hint to proceed further...

Thanks.

Comment: Here is an example MediaController customization: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482203/how-to-create-custom-ui-for-android-mediacontroller/14323144#14323144

Answer (score 6):

You have to write the MediaController Class  all over again extending a FrameLayout .The Layout that it uses should be customised. Get the copy from android source code of MediaController Class and then proceed ahead.

Comment: It refers to internal class PolicyManager which cannot be imported... how to resolve that?

Answer (score 1):

My "solution" was to not set a MediaController for the VideoView. I just created a separate MediaController class that is its own class and did all the custom drawing. This class was just copied from the source code of the real MediaController. In the constructor of my custom MediaController I pass the VideoView and store a reference so I can interact with the VideoView (VideoView has all the methods you need to interact with the MediaPlayer: getCurrentPosition(), getDuration(), resume(), pause(), seekTo(), ...). Let me know if you need more help with it.

Comment: Hi Joris.
Have you a functional example, and you are inflating from XML this Custom Media Controller?
Your solution can allow free position in layout? I need set the position inside of a videoview aligned to left in a relative layout.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back to you sooner. You still need this info? I'm not inflating the custom controller. I just made my own media controller class (it just inherits from Object). You pass it a VideoView object as a mentioned. There is no XML involved.

Comment: @JorisWeimar I also want to create own MediaController Class. please share your source. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

This should be enough:

```
MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);  
mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
videoView.setMediaController(mc);
```

Comment: MediaController by default has fastFWD, rewind, & play/Pause.. my req is differnt, so i wanna customize it

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand you. If you want to customize it, you have to write your own. Unfortunately, there are no additional methods for developers. But it's easy, you can take sources of MC and customize it(there are lot of topics on stackoverflow about it) or write your own (mostly using videoview listners).

Comment: initially wat i want is i wanna customize layout of MC.. i did it using xml Layout, wid the code specified, but the look & feel of MC dint change.. So if u can correct that...

Comment: @Nital what a consistent reply from ania! *-*