# how to create custom UI for android MediaController

Tags: android, android-video-player, mediacontroller

I  want to customize the controls in the MediaController for my video player.
I want to swap out the image for the play button, change the skin, change the color, ect.

Is there a known way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: What have you done until now? Have you tried to code something? Add sample code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044000/change-style-of-android-mediacontroller/36173266#36173266 offers a good solution to change existing elements

Answer (score 105):

I had the same problem on a recent project and ended up creating a custom implementation based on the stock MediaController. It adds a fullscreen button at the far right, but even if that's not what you want this class should be a good starting point.

Code:

- VideoControllerView.java - http://pastebin.com/1V63aVSg
- media_controller.xml - http://pastebin.com/rS4xqMej

Image resources:

- [image]
- [image: http://imgur.com/JYJGN]
- [image: http://imgur.com/R0txq]
- [image: http://imgur.com/dQ6wA]

Gotchas:

- The class assumes the anchor view is a FrameLayout to position itself at the bottom.
- The class does not use a Window to ensure control floats on top of the anchor. However, this hasn't been a problem for me as the show() method does mAnchor.addView() every time.
- The class uses its own MediaPlayerControl protocol. This allows customizations such as toggleFullScreen()

**UPDATE (2013)**: See this tutorial for more details: http://www.brightec.co.uk/blog/custom-android-media-controller

**UPDATE (2018)**: You can now use the wonderful ExoPlayer and fully customize your player UI simply by overriding a layout file.

Comment: @Blago you have an inner class containing a WeakReference to the outer class.  This is useless and doesn't do what you think because an inner class is just syntactic sugar for a top-level class to which you pass a reference to the outer class in the constructor.

Comment: Seekbar doesn't work properly when the user seeks/moves it manually. In that case seekbar stops updating itself.

Comment: Yeah, but you know that this project not is a full because not works correctly (bad assynk + bad instance to generate) but is a good example to start, thanks.

Comment: full screen button not active

Answer (score -6):

I tested it and it works great on 4.4 kitkat, but like KAPLANDROID said blackscreen appeared on android 2.3.6 but the music and videocontroller works fine,

Have found a solution, just put this code

```
videoHolder.setType( SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS );
```

after this

```
videoHolder.addCallback( this );
```

and you are ready to go