# How to get the id of MediaController's buttons in Android

Tags: android, button, mediacontroller

I would like to get the id of the buttons (play, pause, next, previous) inside the mediacontroller. I was able to successfully do that for seekbar following this piece of code:

`final int topContainerId = getResources().getIdentifier("mediacontroller_progress", "id", "android");`

How about for the buttons?

Thank you! :)

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: I would like to modify the buttons.

Comment: In other words you want to customize your MediaController?

Comment: Yes. I just thought that if it is possible to access those buttons, it will be easier to customize the MediaController. If that is possible?

Comment: @kroider read my answer. It is possible but way too complicated.

Comment: Here is an example MediaController customization: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482203/how-to-create-custom-ui-for-android-mediacontroller/14323144#14323144

Comment: With "Layout Inspector" in Android Studio 3, you can easily get the id name "rew", "pause", "ffwd", "prev", "next" by inspect the layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to customize the MediaController, it is possible but it is a very long shot. You have to re-write the MediaController class all over again extending a FrameLayout which you could customize.
I tried to do that but it was way too complicated.
I advise you to use the [MediaPlayer class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) , build your own layout. Thats far more easier.

Comment: Aw. Thank you. I was just hoping that it is possible without having to go through the complicated steps and without switching to MediaPlayer implementation. But it appeared I have to consider your alternatives. Thanks to this immediate response, I am giving you a check. :)

Comment: Thanks! If you need help on MediaPlayer, please ask.