# How can I get a new Window instance on Android?

Tags: java, android, android-view

I am attempting to create a custom Media Controller by duplicating the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/android/widget/MediaController.java#MediaController.initFloatingWindow%28%29) and providing my own layout. The final component is a substitute for `PolicyManager.makeNewWindow(mContext);`
The [PolicyManager](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/com/android/internal/policy/PolicyManager.java#PolicyManager.makeNewWindow%28android.content.Context%29) class is an internal class and I can not seem to find a way to get a new Window. The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html) suggests `new Window(mContext)` but eclipse complains that it 'Cannot instantiate the type Window'. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you use the NDK to access private implementations, you cannot actually create a `Window`. I have done exactly what you are trying with an embedded system, but it is not safe to do for a general purpose app (the underlying implementations have changed and will change again).

Regardless of whether you are using a `SurfaceView` or `TextureView` for the `MediaPlayer`, you should be able to a achieve a similar effect with a regular old transparent custom `View`. The separate `Window` shouldn't be necessary. It won't be as easy as copying Android's `MediaController` code, but it shouldn't be too complicated.

Also, if all you want is a different layout and not a drastic change in functionality, have a look at these **[two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482203/how-to-create-custom-ui-for-android-mediacontroller)**  **[links](http://www.brightec.co.uk/blog/custom-android-media-controller)** (the second refers to the first, but it adds commentary & an example project).

Comment: No, NativeActivity steals the whole surface from the Window, causing the window to not draw at all.  You need to create a separate window if you need to draw anything at that point.

Comment: I don't see what NativeActivity has to do with any of this. I'm also not sure what part of my answer you are saying "no" to. Perhaps you think NativeActivity is the only way to use native code?