# How to handle VideoView?

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am working on a simple demo app, in which I play a video using VideoView.

**What is my Query:**

- When I touch on the VideoView. It'll Show me status of the Video.

`Like: pause / next / previous / seek bar / etc, which mention in the Image as u notice.`
[image]

These all things come with in a **`translucent background`** and  I want this  in **`transparent background`**. Even I tried but i couldn't get anything related to this.!

Is there any method or way in VideoView for handle this or not ? please let me know

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own MediaController class and then do:

```
videoView.setMediaController(yourMediaController);
```

See this other post:
[how to create custom UI for android MediaController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482203/how-to-create-custom-ui-for-android-mediacontroller/14323144#14323144)