# Disable seekforward and seekbackward of mediacontroller android?

Tags: android, android-videoview, mediacontroller, mpmediaplayercontroller

I am playing a video from url and I want to disable the seekbar tracking of the video. How can it be done.

This my code:

```
videoUrl = "http://download.itcuties.com/teaser/itcuties-teaser-480.mp4";
    videoview.setVideoPath(videoUrl);
    mediaController = new MediaController(this, false);
    int topContainerId = getResources().getIdentifier("mediacontroller_progress", "id", "android");
    seekBarVideo=(SeekBar)mediaController.findViewById(topContainerId);
    seekBarVideo.setEnabled(false);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoview);
    videoview.setMediaController(mediaController);
```

The app crashes:  seekBarVideo.setEnabled(false);

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.vfirst.offers.VideoBufferActivity.onClick(VideoBufferActivity.java:93)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4575)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18578)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5127)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was able to solve with help of this

Need to get seekbar in onPreparedListener of videoview

```
 videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            int topContainerId = getResources().getIdentifier("mediacontroller_progress", "id", "android");
            seekBarVideo = (SeekBar) mediaController.findViewById(topContainerId);
            seekBarVideo.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    seekBar.setEnabled(false);
                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    seekBar.setEnabled(false);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try creating a custom mediacontroller UI without a seekbar. Check this post
[how to create custom UI for android MediaController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482203/how-to-create-custom-ui-for-android-mediacontroller)

or try out a hack, gain access to seekbar and set visibility to `GONE`

```
final int progressBarId = getResources().getIdentifier("mediacontroller_progress", "id", "android");
final SeekBar seekbar = (SeekBar) mController.findViewById(progressBarId);
```

**EDIT**

Try looping through child views inside MediaController till you find a seek bar, then hide it

```
private void styleMediaController(View view) {
        if (view instanceof MediaController) {
            MediaController v = (MediaController) view;
            for(int i = 0; i < v.getChildCount(); i++) {
                styleMediaController(v.getChildAt(i));
            }
        } else
        if (view instanceof LinearLayout) {
            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) view;
            for(int i = 0; i < ll.getChildCount(); i++) {
                styleMediaController(ll.getChildAt(i));
            }
        } else if (view instanceof SeekBar) {
            // set progress bar color
            SeekBar seeker = (SeekBar) view;
            //hide seekbar here
        }
  }
```

Comment: mController is the object of MediaController?

Comment: that is the worst thing to do. Media player was already managing multiple UI changes and if you loop it, it will cause chaos.