# Media Controller properly isn't working for VideoView in Android

Tags: java, android, android-videoview, android-seekbar

The following are the problems :

1. The seeker doesn't move as the video goes forward
2. The seeker doesn't seek to the desired position instead, the video starts all over again.
3. The forward and backward buttons don't work.

Here is my code:

```
 VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
 videoView.setVideoPath("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.video);
 MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
 mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
 videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
 videoView.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can look this
   [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32064597/8956604)
2. Probably the first answer solves the problem
3. Add listener like this:

   ```
   mediaController.setPrevNextListeners(onClickListenerNext, onClickListenerPrevious);

   private View.OnClickListener onClickListenerNext = new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
         videoView.setVideoURI(nextVideoUri);
         videoView.start();
     }
   };
   private View.OnClickListener onClickListenerPrevious = new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
         videoView.setVideoURI(previousVideoUri);
         videoView.start();
     }
   };
   ```