# Custom UI on exoplayer sample

Tags: android, mediacontroller, exoplayer

** I really need help if you don't know anything don't give me a negative point :| if something bother you comment**

I want to write custom UI for my player in Exoplayer(change button of pause play or add new buttons like player speed next and etc) .

I use Exoplayer sample from github and before add code to my original project, I want to test the custom UI on official sample.

I read pages in Stackoverflow and tuts+ about custom UI but I really confused!

why change some buttons image or change their place must be so difficult :) how i can handle this?

**EDIT**

this is the sample
https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/master/demo

I read these two article:

http://www.brightec.co.uk/ideas/custom-android-media-controller

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-user-controls--mobile-22787

according to this [link](http://brightec.co.uk/ideas/custom-android-media-controller) "Instead of writing your own media controller from scratch, you could start with the MediaController class that is included in Android" and I ask this question because i can't do this steps on exoplayer library and tutorial is written for default media player

Comment: Please explain your problem in more detail. What have you tried? It would be helpful to see the necessary parts of your code.

Comment: @Christopher I edit post. the main problem is I can't try anything because Exoplayer library is very complex :) Idon't know where i have to edit and overide. I try on sample as i mentioned

Comment: I think you only have to change https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/master/demo/src/main/res/layout/player_activity.xml

Comment: @Christopher no the play and other controller implement in code they set in this:
mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(root);
i'm not senior but I developed some good and simple application in this 2 year :) it was really complicated and i so angry with people who give me negative :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually the code of involking play & pause methods are in class [PlayerControl](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/0c060f429f459f1bac2ffa0963cadc45ce35b73a/library/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/util/PlayerControl.java#L90).

If you don't want to use default Android media controller UI, just don't use the `MediaController` class, create your own UI in your layout file with custom play & pause button and bind the actions with the button's onClickListener.

To play the video, call `exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);`

And to pause:  call `exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);`

It's similar problem with [how to create custom UI for android MediaController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482203/how-to-create-custom-ui-for-android-mediacontroller)

Comment: according to this link(http://www.brightec.co.uk/ideas/custom-android-media-controller) "Instead of writing your own media controller from scratch, you could start with the MediaController class that is included in Android" and I ask this question because i can't do this steps on exoplayer library and tutorial is written for default media player

Comment: after 5 years your solution does make more sense to me :)) I don't know if it works or not because I don't work on any player anymore but it looks reasonable to me :D sorry I was junior and I didn't have a mentor :D

Answer (score 40):

Customizing the ExoPlayer's UI is pretty simple. If you look at the ExoPlayer source, the layout res directory contains the file `exo_player_control_view.xml` that points to (includes) another layout - `exo_playback_control_view`.

1. Copy the contents of the layout resource - `exo_playback_control_view.xml`
2. Create a Layout Resource file with any name of your choice - eg: `custom_exo_playback_control_view.xml`. Paste the copied contents to the new xml
3. Make whatever changes to the UI widgets as required. Don't change the Id attribute of any widget/control.
4. Point the custom exoPlayer UI resource in your layout file that contains the `PlayerView`.

Here is the `custom_exo_controller_view` xml that I created from the original. I wanted a different background color for the player controls and different button and progress view colors:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@drawable/attachment_document_desc_bg"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:paddingEnd="20dp"
    tools:targetApi="28">

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:paddingTop="4dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@id/exo_prev"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Previous"
        android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:tintMode="src_in" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@id/exo_rew"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Rewind"
        android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:tintMode="src_in" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@id/exo_shuffle"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Shuffle"
        android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:tintMode="src_in" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@id/exo_repeat_toggle"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton"
        android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:tintMode="src_in" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@id/exo_play"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Play"
        android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:tintMode="src_in" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@id/exo_pause"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Pause"
        android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:tintMode="src_in" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@id/exo_ffwd"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.FastForward"
        android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:tintMode="src_in" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@id/exo_next"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Next"
        android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:tintMode="src_in" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@id/exo_vr"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.VR"
        android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:tintMode="src_in" />

  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
      android:gravity="center_vertical"
      android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/exo_position"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:textColor="#ff323232"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar
        android:id="@id/exo_progress"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:played_color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:unplayed_color="@color/gray" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/exo_duration"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:textColor="#ff323232"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Below is the code that I use for the player. Notice, the xml attribute `app:controller_layout_id` points to the custom controller view thats defined above.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp">

  <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
      android:id="@+id/video_view"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      app:auto_show="true"
      app:controller_layout_id="@layout/custom_exo_controller_view"
      app:fastforward_increment="10000"
      app:repeat_toggle_modes="none"
      app:resize_mode="fixed_width"
      app:rewind_increment="10000"
      app:surface_type="surface_view"
      app:use_controller="true" />

</FrameLayout>
```

That should get the UI the way you want.

You can add extra controls as you need in the custom controller and in your code, find the control with `findViewById()` and write event listeners, etc.

Comment: Suppose if I want to add a button to this layout how can I add on-click listener on this button from the code? I am using data binding and when I type binding.playerview. there is no custom button id coming up to add on click listener. Can you let me know this? I am stuck at this and not able to make any progress.

Comment: @PrahladVThej, I doubt if you can use data binding with the exoplayer yet. I think there is a feature request in their Git Repo. Besides, I haven't tried it. You may refer to this link: https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia/issues/456

Answer (score 21):

ok, that took me half a day, until i didn't dive into the library code and found such text:

To customize the layout of PlaybackControlView throughout your app, or just for certain configurations, you can define ***exo_playback_control_view.xml*** layout file in your application ***res/layout*** directories. These layouts will override the one provided by the ExoPlayer library, and will be inflated for use by PlaybackControlView.

Full text: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/library/ui/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/PlaybackControlView.java

Also, want to add that u can specify custom layout in PlayerView like so:

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView android:id="@+id/player_view"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:controller_layout_id="@layout/custom_controls"/>
```

Comment: Can we add controller_layout_id programatically?

Comment: try to extend PlaybackControlView.java and add this method =)

Comment: which method please?

Comment: I dont get it... Is there an example?

Comment: Deprecated.....