# Customize MediaController in Exoplayer 2

Tags: android, mediacontroller, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I'd like to customize entirely the ExoPlayer Media Controller, separating the Controller from the View itself.

I saw several posts about Exoplayer 1 version (this one is really useful: [Custom UI on exoplayer sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33647496/custom-ui-on-exoplayer-sample))
but nothing about Exoplayer 2 (which is what I'm using).

The code between versions 1 and 2 is changed and I cannot find any way to retrieve the same MediaController as in the version 1.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Press *Ctrl+Shift+N* find **exo_simple_player_view.xml** in ExoPlayer library resources, copy it to your own resources and customize it as you wish, but don't change view ids. 
It works only if you are using **SimpleExoPlayerView** (it will automatically search for layout with such id and use it)

Answer (score 0):

the ExoPlayer Media Controller is declare in SimpleExoPlayerView, so you should use custom view instead of SimpleExoPlayerView.