# ExoPlayer: Place controller under the video without overlapping the video

Tags: java, android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I have a `PlayerView` that takes up the top half of the Activity in portrait orientation with the bottom half of the screen showing some text.

I need to have the controller **under the video without overlapping the video content** (it will always be shown). By default when a user touches the video the controller appears at the bottom of the video covering the bottom part of the video. I my case I need the controller to stick under the video with no intersections with the video content.

I went through `SimpleExoPlayer` and `PlayerView` APIs but I haven't found any way to do so.

**Question:** How can I place the controller under the video with ExoPlayer?

Here is how the layout looks like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/video_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you should edit exoplayer layout by import exoplayer as a module

Comment: can you please post as a image of your problem for better understanding

Comment: @WaleedAsim can't post right now. But I updated the question with more explanation (hope it is clear now).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33647496/custom-ui-on-exoplayer-sample may be this helps you

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This will push the controls down to the bottom of the screen:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:use_controller="false" />

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerControlView
        android:id="@+id/controls"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/video_view"
        app:show_timeout="0" />
   
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in Java:

```
PlayerView videoView = findViewById(R.id.video_view);
PlayerControlView controls = findViewById(R.id.controls);
controls.setPlayer(videoView.getPlayer());
```

**Edit:** Modified my answer to suggestion from **@RashimiGautam**

Comment: Thank you. This way I'd have two controls at the same time. Do you know how to remove the original one?

Comment: @OleksandrShpota see if the edited answer works for you

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Though `PlaybackControlView` is deprecated - I replaced it with `PlayerControlView`.

Comment: I updated your answer with the final solution that worked for me.

Comment: You can't set PlayerView in controls.setPlayer(videoView).

Comment: You need to pass ExoPlayer reference to the controls.setPlayer(player)

Answer (score 9):

Refer to the answer by ***@Pierre***.
Also to remove controller from above `PlayerView`, in that case, `@id/video_view` by writing `player.showController(false)` in java file.
You can also use `app:use_controller:false` in the xml.
So you will the only the video without controller on top. And link it to a new controller, in that case, `@id/controls` at the bottom of the video.

Answer (score 4):

This might give you an idea, also have you [tried to override the controls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41631901/2520628)?

As an example, suppose we want our playback controls to consist of only a play/pause button positioned in the center of the view. We can achieve this by creating `exo_playback_control_view.xml` file in the application’s res/layout directory, containing:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_play"
      android:layout_width="100dp"
      android:layout_height="100dp"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:background="#CC000000"
      style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Play"/>

  <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_pause"
      android:layout_width="100dp"
      android:layout_height="100dp"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:background="#CC000000"
      style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Pause"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Note that in the layout `@id/exo_play` and `@id/exo_pause` are standard ids defined by the ExoPlayer library. Use of standard ids is required so that child views can be identified, bound to the player and updated in an appropriate way. A full list of the standard ids for each view can be found in the Javadoc for [PlaybackControlView](http://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/index.html?com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/PlaybackControlView.html) and [SimpleExoPlayerView](http://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/index.html?com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/SimpleExoPlayerView.html). Use of each standard id is optional.

https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/customizing-exoplayers-ui-components-728cf55ee07a

Comment: I've got how to hide all buttons except Play and Pause. But how can I stick the control bar under the video view?

Comment: you can override the control bar and then place it under the video