# How to implement ExoPlayer with Databinding?

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I have a class `activity_player` layout in which I have `exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView` and I created `exo_player_control_view` so that it overrides default controls in ExoPlayer. So I wanted to use Databinding in newly created custom control view but don't know how to do it. Any advice?

It is actually an open issue over [here](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/5417), but yet to be solved. So is there anyone who had a workaround to make `exo_player_control_view` Databinding friendly?

Comment: Are you found any solution ?

Comment: No actually. I am following that open issue but no solution yet

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @Shri no not at all. I think it would be really complicated say if we suppose make custom ExoPlayer and bind layout with DataBinding. I gave the link for an open issue regarding this on ExoPlayer repo. But it's yet to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

After Lot of Searching
Found the solution

Here is the suggested solution
**Add an ID to the root tag of custom controls**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
 android:id="@+id/dragon_exo_control_layout"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 ...
 >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/hello"
    ... 
    />

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Next In your activity onCreate()**

```
YourBindingControlClass exoControlBinding = YourBindingControlClass.bind(findViewByID(R.id.dragon_exo_control_layout));

  // Then use it like
  exoControlBinding.setText("Hello, World !");
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Like this >>>>>

```
private val binding by lazy {
     ActivityPipVideoPlayerBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)}

private val exoPLayerBinding by lazy {
    VdoExoControlViewBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(this), binding.root, true)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use binding variable inside fragment/activity to access the playerView inside fragment/activity and

```
  val uri: Uri? = if (url is String) Uri.parse(url as String?) else url as Uri?
    val trackSelector =
        DefaultTrackSelector(AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(DefaultBandwidthMeter()))
    val player: SimpleExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(view.context, trackSelector)
    val dataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(view.context, "ua")
    val mediaSource =
        ExtractorMediaSource(uri, dataSourceFactory, DefaultExtractorsFactory(), null, null)
    player.prepare(mediaSource)
    player.apply {
        volume = 0f
        repeatMode = Player.REPEAT_MODE_ONE
        playWhenReady = true
        videoScalingMode = C.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT
    }
    binding.playerView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FILL)
    binding.playerView.player = player
```

Comment: I suppose you are referring to use Databinding with PlayerView inside you `activity_player.xml`, but my intention is to use Databinding with Custom control view which can be done by creating new layout file `exo_player_control_view.xml`. As in Databinding with custom buttons of `exo_player_control_view`

Comment: yeah you can hide the default controls and add a custom control view if needed

Comment: Yeah so my question was how to control that `exo_player_control_view` items with Databinding?

Comment: please go through this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/41631901/8601451

Comment: Well, as I said I am not asking who to set custom controls, but use those custom controls with Databinding. I guess you didn't get my question. It is in fact an open issue here, So asked in StackOverflow if somehow has work around anyhow.