# PlayerView custom controlls

Tags: android, android-layout, customization, exoplayer

I am trying to set up custom controlls for my exoplayer.

**My work based on this:**

[Custom UI on exoplayer sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33647496/custom-ui-on-exoplayer-sample#56705173)

**and this:**

https://exoplayer.dev/ui-components.html

I've create `custom_player_ui.xml` in `res/layout` with one custom button (not because of this, I was trying to build without this one) and standart id's like:

```
<ImageButton
       android:id="@+id/exo_fullscreen"
       style="@style/ExoMediaButton"
       android:src="@drawable/expandexo"
       android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
       android:tintMode="src_in" />
<ImageButton
        android:id="@id/exo_prev"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Previous"
        android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:tintMode="src_in" />
```

and define it in my `PlayerView`:

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
    android:id="@+id/player_view_channels"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:use_controller="false"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:rewind_increment="10000"
    app:fastforward_increment="10000"
    android:background="#000"
    app:show_timeout="1000"
    app:resize_mode="fit"
    app:controller_layout_id="@layout/custom_player_ui" />
```

but I'm getting nothing in xml editor and activity.

**What else must be done for displaying my controlls?**

Comment: app:controller_layout_id="@layout/playback_control_view_mini"
try this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Need to add Controls too:**

```
    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerControlView
        android:id="@+id/controls"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:show_timeout="0" />
```