# Exoplayer 2.17.1 Customize UI layout without using exoplayer UI library

Tags: android, android-layout, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, exoplayer-media-item

I need to develop an application in which Exoplayer is used for streaming media's. Is it possible to use the app were to implement its own playback controls and hence not need the UI components provided by the library, just depend on the Core ? **Mainly, I need to edit the Id attribute of any widget/control in exoplayer UI library.**

Reference: [Custom UI on exoplayer sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33647496/custom-ui-on-exoplayer-sample#56705173)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.