# How to set fullscreen option with android videoview?

Tags: android, video

I have videos I am implementing in my app and I need to know if it is possible to set a feature on the videoview to allow a fullscreen option like there is on youtube videos.

Below is my code to put the video on the videoview and I currently have a mediacontroller on it so I can start, pause and go back and forward in the video but I need the full screen option as the videos are coming fuzzy as they are too small on the current dimensions but would be much clearer on the full screen.

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.Vidview1);
                VideoView video1 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
                //Setting the path to the 'basics' file in the raw resources file
                String urlpath = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.intro;
                video1.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(urlpath));
                //setting the playbar/media controller
                video1.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
                layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Try setting the  SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN flag. (Link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN)

Comment: You can create custom media controllers with full-screen option

Comment: video1.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);  this is what I tried, it did not work however.

Comment: @Kathi how would I go about achieving that, I found this question from another stack overflow user http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482203/how-to-create-custom-ui-for-android-mediacontroller , would this be a good way to do it?

Comment: @GChanna that is good to go.  Are you expecting default *full screen* option ?

Comment: No I want the video to play in the videoview and the media controller to have a button next to the play/pause button for a full screen option, and that question looks to have what I asked for